# GPU memory when using hardware acceleration

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have repeatedly run into the problem on colab (esp. when using PyTorch) where an interrupted kernel that is using the `.cuda()` method will run out of memory when restarted.

A colleague suggested that the GPU memory is shared between different users on the colab platform. This seems like a really bad idea, but could be one answer to this problem. Can anyone confirm that hardware accelerators are dedicated to a particular user's session on colab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed that each HW accelerator is assigned to a single user, and that each notebook gets its own hardware assignment.
(the former has been true since launch, the latter has become true more recently).

The question uses the expression "user's session" but doesn't define it. For concreteness, the exclusivity described above applies to the (user,notebook) pair.
(and doesn't, for example, include the browser tab).

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation or a snippet that can show this?

Comment: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html makes several statements about "virtual machine" including that it "will not be shared"  and that it is "dedicated to your account" (no sharing of HW resources among users) and implies multiple VMs via "all managed virtual machines assigned to you" but does not explicitly state a resource policy.

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb includes some examples of how to interrogate the available TPU hardware, and [!nvidia-smi] will do the same for GPUs.

Comment: The FAQ link seems to be the closest answer that I was trying to find, esp. the statement "Code is executed in a virtual machine dedicated to your account.".